# Does C# have an `std::back_insert_iterator<>` equivalent in C++?

Tags: c#, c++

Using `std::back_insert_iterator<>`, I ever wrote following smooth code in C++

```
std::back_insert_iterator<> fack_fn(std::back_insert_iterator<> iter)
{
  *iter++ = 0xAA;
  *iter++ = 0xBB;
  return iter;
}
```

When I am using C#, I wrote out these shxxxt code to mimic my C++ experience.

```
public static Span<byte>.Enumerator fake_2(Span<byte>.Enumerator iter)
{
  iter.Current = 0xAA;
  iter.MoveNext();

  iter.Current = 0xBB;
  iter.MoveNext();

  return iter;
}
```

I'm just curious that do we have an `std::back_insert_iterator<>` equivalent in C#?

Comment: The usual choice would be using an interface, such as `IList<T>`

Comment: You're trying to use concepts from one language in another language, this is usually not a good idea

Comment: `AddRange` appends multiple items to many containers in a single call. C++ developers would argue about the "smoothness", safety and cost  of the C++ code. `vector` uses an array as a backing store so a single insert can result in the reallocation of a full array.

Comment: `Enumerable.Concat` and `Enumerable.Append`   work with C#'s notion of iterators. However, the C++ pattern isn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

> Does C# have an `std::back_insert_iterator<>` equivalent in C++?

Not really. The closest to an "iterator" would be `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator`, but this does not allow insertions.

You could use one of the collection interfaces. The simplest would probably be [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.add?view=net-8.0). This is implemented by most of the common, simple, collection types.

You could also create a delegate of the add method (or any similar method), this would probably be the closest option if I understand the documentation of [back_insert_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) correctly.

```
var list = new List<int>();
Action<int> addDelegate = list.Add;
addDelegate(42);
```

In the end it will depend on what you are trying to do. C++ and C# are fairly different languages, with different programming styles and practices. You should try to adapt your style to the target language.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict callers to only be able to add items to a collection, you could wrap a `List<T>` in a simple class like so:

```
public sealed class BackInserter<T>
{
    readonly List<T> _collection;

    public BackInserter(List<T> collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }

    public BackInserter<T> Add(T item)
    {
        _collection.Add(item);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then your `fack_fn()` method would look something like this (in C# style):

```
BackInserter<byte> FackFn(BackInserter<byte> iter)
{
    iter.Add(0xAA);
    iter.Add(0xBB);

    return iter;
}
```

I would recommend NOT using `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>` because both of those would allow you to attempt to use an array with `BackInserter` - and trying to call `.Add()` for an array will throw an exception.

If you really wanted to you could add an implicit operator to convert a `List<T>` to a `BackInserter<T>` by adding this to the class:

```
public static implicit operator BackInserter<T>(List<T> list)
{
    return new BackInserter<T>(list);
}
```

Then you could call a method that accepts a `BackInserter<T>` with a `List<T>` without having to explicitly create a `BackInserter<T>`:

```
var list = new List<byte>();
FackFn(list);
```

I fear this might be a bit too subtle for general use, though... YMMV.

Comment: I suspect `AddRange` alone would be better than trying to emulate C++

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, I'm inclined to agree.